# How to configure read only access and admin access for EKS in aws sso with azure ad?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, amazon-eks

I want to configure AWS SSO to access EKS with Azure AD. However, I want to have two access types i.e. Read only and Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to map the AD groups to AWS IAM roles via AWS SSO AssumedRoles. We will then use Kubernetes configMaps and roles to map the associated IAM roles to Kubernetes RBAC roles. This will be done by leveraging the open source AWS IAM Authenticator to pass an IAM identity from kubectl.
In the below example, users in the AWS-EKS-Admins group have full access to the EKS cluster (similar to the permissions assigned to the default cluster-admin role within Kubernetes) and users in the AWS-EKS-Dev group have readOnly access to certain Kubernetes resources. The mapping is summarized in the table below:

[AWS EKS Permission mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3w8M.jpg)

Please refer the below aws documentation link for more reference: -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/integrating-ldap-ad-users-kubernetes-rbac-aws-iam-authenticator-project/

Thanking you,